# Error: nombre de columna desconocido

Tags: java, mysql

Se supone que obtengo el último valor de id para luego con un conjunto de jTextfield recolectar más información de los datos.

En este caso tengo una tabla llamada `camion` y sus atributos son placa, marca, modelo, idchofer (obtengo el ultimo id registrado). Esto es lo que obtengo haciendo `DESCRIBE camion;`:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|  placa   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| marca    | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modelo   | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| idchofer | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Pero me salta un error que no tengo ni idea de cuál será la falla. Anexo el error:

> GRAVE: null
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'placa' in 'field list'

Y el código:

```
public void agregarCamion(){
  
             String placa= s.jTextField9.getText();
            String marca=s.jTextField10.getText();
            String modelo=s.jTextField11.getText();
             
        try {
          int n= 0;
   getConexion();
     Statement stm = con.createStatement();
     // almaceno resultado de consulta en ResultSet
     ResultSet rs  = stm.executeQuery("select MAX(idchofer) AS id from chofer");
     
     if(rs.next()) {
       //obtengo el valor del ultimo id y lo guardo en n
        n= rs.getInt(1);
         System.out.println("datos es :" +n);
         
          ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO camion(placa,marca,modelo,idchofer)VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");
         
            ps.setString(1,placa);
            ps.setString(2, marca);
            ps.setString(3,modelo);
               ps.setInt(4, n);
               
            int res=ps.executeUpdate();
            res=ps.executeUpdate();
         
            if (res>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "se agrego los datos");
    }
     }
    
       
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
              
              
          
}
```

Comment: Parece que hay un espacio en blanco antes de la palabra placa cuando haces el `DESCRIBE`. ¿Seguro que el nombre de la columna es `"placa"` y no `" placa"`?

Comment: acabo de fijarme en ese error ya le quite el espacion pero ahora el error es este:java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da ese error? Por favor, edita la pregunta con la nueva información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITO: Como mal programador que soy, sé aceptar cuando me equivoco de hipótesis, jajaja.
El primer código que escribiste estaba bien. No tendrías que haber agregado las comillas, como yo te dije. El problema era el espacio en blanco en el nombre del campo, no en el query. El query original estaba bien hecho, ya que validás que sea String en el prepareStatement (setString), y eso ya te agrega las comillas en el query (mala mía).

Por ende, el query dejalo como estaba antes:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO camion (placa,marca,modelo,idchofer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

El error que te tira ahora (Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)) es culpa de mi query loco.

---

COMENTARIO ANTERIOR (Hipótesis errónea):

Te comento. Cuando insertás un varchar (un String) en SQL, lo tenés que poner entre comillas. Por ende, probá de escribir tu query así:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO camion (placa,marca,modelo,idchofer) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', ?)");
```

Comment: ahora el error es este: GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

Comment: Tenés razón, no va con comillas, jaja. Estaba bien lo que habías escrito: INSERT INTO camion(placa,marca,modelo,idchofer)VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)
Porque el set lo estás haciendo como setString.

Es probable que el problema sea lo que te dice el usuario Alvaro Montoro

Comment: funciona pero cuando ingreso un dato me lanza el error como si ubiera repetido la llave primaria osea placa:GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '777' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Bueno, ahí tenés otro problema, y es que estás tratando de insertar valores duplicados en la primary key. 

Eso quiere decir que tenés 2 placas con el valor 777. Acá tenés varias opciones: o bien limpiás la data, o bien validás que no venga duplicado, o bien ponés en tu consulta la sentencia IGNORE:

INSERT IGNORE INTO camion (placa,marca,modelo,idchofer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Eso va a ignorar los duplicados (pero depende lo que quieras hacer). También podés usar "ON DUPLICATE KEY ... ",en donde podés (en vez de ignorarlo) actualizarlo. Pero todo depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Para que se entienda: La primary key es un valor único. Es como un índice. No puede tener valores duplicados, ya que es tu referencia cuando tengas que buscar cosas haciendo un SELECT, o cuando tengas que relacionar tu tabla con otra.

Que sea único ese campo está bien (y en el caso que vos ponés, está bien que la placa sea la primary key del camión, ya que hay una sola placa por camión).

Comment: ok ya cree un nuevo chofer para que conduzca un nuevo camión borre todos los datos de camión y añadí uno nuevo y salta que esta duplicado otra vez :c

Comment: Debe ser que estás entrando 2 veces a ese código. Fijate si hacés un System.out.println("entro") y te va a entrar 2 veces seguramente. Ahí vas a tener que buscar por qué razón entra dos veces.

Comment: gracias amigo era porque se llamaba al metodo executeUpdate(); dos veces.

Answer (score 0):

amigo, deberias empezar corrigiendo lo que vas a enviar como valor, ya que cuando es texto en este caso varchar, debes ponerlo entre comillas simples. en este caso tienes el simbolo de interrogacion ? , haz la prueba colocando un texto plano como ejemplo: INSERT INTO camion (placa,marca,modelo,idchofer) VALUES ('AA123', 'toyota', 'corolla', 1)  claro suponinedo que el tienes el id 1 en la tabla idchofer
hazlo y comentanos como te va

Comment: ahora el error es este: GRAVE: null java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)